# How to stop animationset in Android?

Tags: android, android-animation

I have following class. Depends on something I should start/stop animation dynamically. I'm able to run the animation by calling its `startAnimation()` method however, animation does not stop when I call `stopAnimation()`. The interesting thing is even `ivSonar1` and `ivSonar2` are still visible after calling `stopAnimation()` method.

```
public class SonarView extends RelativeLayout
{
    private static final int ANIM_LENGTH_IN_MS = 1500;

    private ImageView ivSonar1;
    private ImageView ivSonar2;

    private AnimationSet animationSet1;
    private AnimationSet animationSet2;

    public SonarView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
    }

    public SonarView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public SonarView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public SonarView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
    {
        // try to make it 25% smaller than its real size to make enough room for items of biding list
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec * 3 / 4, heightMeasureSpec * 3 / 4);

        ivSonar1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivSonar1);
        ivSonar1.setVisibility(INVISIBLE);
        ivSonar2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivSonar2);
        ivSonar2.setVisibility(INVISIBLE);

        float maxWidth = findViewById(R.id.ivBackground).getMeasuredWidth();

        animationSet1 = createAnimationSet(ivSonar1, maxWidth / ivSonar1.getMeasuredWidth());
        animationSet2 = createAnimationSet(ivSonar2, maxWidth / ivSonar2.getMeasuredWidth());
        animationSet2.setStartOffset(150);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onFinishInflate()
    {
        super.onFinishInflate();

        LayoutInflater.from(this.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.widget_sonar_view, this, true);
    }

    private AnimationSet createAnimationSet(final View v, final float toScale)
    {
        // Set animation
        final AnimationSet animationSet = new AnimationSet(true);
        animationSet.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
        animationSet.setDuration(SonarView.ANIM_LENGTH_IN_MS);
        animationSet.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation)
            {
                v.setAlpha(1.0f);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation)
            {
                v.setAlpha(0.0f);

                animationSet.setStartOffset(0);
                v.startAnimation(animationSet);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation)
            {

            }
        });

        // TODO The scale animation should ideally scaled to the size of the outer ring, hacking it here instead to use alpha so that I don't have to the calculation right now. Will come back to this.
        // Alpha animation
        animationSet.addAnimation(new AlphaAnimation(1.0f, 0.0f));
        // Scale animation
        animationSet.addAnimation(new ScaleAnimation(0.0f, toScale, 0.0f, toScale, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
                        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f));

        return animationSet;
    }

    public void stopAnimation()
    {
        if (ivSonar1 == null || ivSonar2 == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        ivSonar1.setVisibility(INVISIBLE);
        ivSonar2.setVisibility(INVISIBLE);

        animationSet1.cancel();
        animationSet2.cancel();

        ivSonar1.clearAnimation();
        ivSonar2.clearAnimation();
    }

    public void startAnimation()
    {
        if (ivSonar1 == null || ivSonar2 == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        ivSonar1.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
        ivSonar2.setVisibility(VISIBLE);

        animationSet1.reset();
        animationSet2.reset();
        animationSet2.setStartOffset(150);

        ivSonar1.startAnimation(animationSet1);
        ivSonar2.startAnimation(animationSet2);
    }
}
```

Comment: you can try clearAnimation() method of view.

Comment: Just a guess, probably ivSonar1/ivSonar2 variables are not set when you call stopAnimation.

Comment: @muratgu I confirm all methods of `stopAnimation` gets called since I debugged it. hmm, it around 4 hours I'm on it :(

Answer (score 0):

To stop the `AnimationSet` you may need to also remove any listeners:

```
animationSet.setAnimationListener(null);
animationSet.cancel();
```